# Windows Powershell: Shortcut for change directory

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line, command-line-interface

I just started using Windows Powershell and one major problem I've run into is when I start it, it starts me off in this directory:

```
C:\Users\Username
```

However, the directory I usually need to navigate to is in something like:

```
C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Websites\2014\Projects\ProjectName
```

And sometimes it goes much deeper. So you can see how it is a little annoying to navigate each time I start the shell to this directory using ten separate cd commands. I was wondering if there was a way to set up a shortcut or alias for something like:

```
cd C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Websites\2014\Projects\ProjectName
```

Or possibly I could set some sort of shortcut to the directory only so I could do something like:

```
cd shortcut
```

And it would cd to the proper directory. Does anyone have any experience with something like this? Is this a dumb thing to do? I'm very new to using any command line so I'm just trying to get used to navigating around files and folders more easily.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233659/open-powershell-in-a-specific-directory-from-shortcut

Comment: I wasn't specifically asking to have it start in one directory, but more along the lines of setting up shortcuts to get to different directories on the fly. So I don't consider this a duplicate.

Comment: What do you think about the part in my answer about using environment variables to set up shortcuts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run this in powershell:

```powershell
start notepad $profile
```

That will open up your profile in notepad (notepad will prompt you to create it if it doesn't exist).

Any code you write in this `.ps1` file will be executed when powershell starts.

You can also set a system environment variable, like if you were to set `MYPSPATH` equal to `C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Websites\2014\Projects` then you could do this:

```
cd $env:MYPSPATH
```

That could be done either manually each time, or automatically within your `$profile`.

Also it's unclear from your question, but it sounds like you're doing a `cd` for every path component.

There's no need to do that. This command that you wished for:

```
cd C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Websites\2014\Projects\ProjectName
```

will work as is. If I misunderstood this point I apologize.

Something that also might be useful to you is `pushd` which is an alias of `Push-Location`. This lets you change to a new directory and easily revert back where you started with `popd` or `Pop-Location`.

```
PS C:\users\Xenostar> Push-Location .\Dropox\Websites\2014\Projects
PS C:\users\Xenostar\Dropbox\Websites\2014\Projects> Pop-Location
PS C:\users\Xenostar>
```

And you can push multiple levels deep, and keep popping back to the previous ones.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer to me. From this I basically learned about setting up profiles in Powershell, which has really opened a whole new realm of possibilities for me now with setting alias and other random settings to get the shortcuts I desire. Thank you!

Comment: When I run `start notepad $profile`, Notepad gives me an error saying `The system cannot find the path specified`.

Comment: @cornflakes24 it still works for me. Make sure you're running that from powershell, not the windows command prompt.

Comment: @cornflakes24 You will have to create the profile, use `New-Item -Path $PROFILE -Type File` as described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/126469/how-to-create-a-powershell-profile/)

Comment: recommend `ise $profile` to launch the "Integrated Scripting Environment" for Powershell (gives you highlighting and code completion) instead of notepad

Answer (score 21):

There is also another way to do this:

```
function PP { cd C:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Websites\2014\Projects\ProjectName }

Set-Alias shortcut `PP`
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've found so far for people like me used to bash. I'm not used to `cd`'ing into an alias, but rather used to calling the alias to take me to a folder.

Comment: The Set-Alias is not required. You can just type 'PP' to execute the function

Answer (score 15):

new-psdrive is your friend :

```
New-PSDrive -Name docs -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "C:\Users\username\Documents"
cd docs:
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the documentation you are looking for to change the default location where powershell starts up: [The Windows PowerShell Profile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692764.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't directly answer the question, I found using this utility makes navigating around in powershell far easier: https://github.com/rupa/z

Install using `Install-Module z -AllowClobber`

Then navigate with `z whatever` where it will match "whatever" against your most frequently visited folders.

Answer (score -2):

If the directory you want to go is named X; then write cd X:\